# Error of declaration of variable

Tags: matlab

I have a problem at the beginning of my function. The function is to combine several data column from some objects. Error happens at the beginning of function. It says as follows:

> Error in find_by_coor (line 2)
>          for i = 1:length(obj_ac)

Here is only the declaration of variable and loop, but Matlab somehow returned error. I have no idea so would like someone to help me. I attached my code as follows. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
function arr = find_by_coor(obj_ac,obj_gps,obj_sen_dir,lat1,long1,lat2,long2)
    for i = 1:length(obj_ac)
       if eq(obj_sen_dir(i).sensor,4) && strcmp(obj_sen_dir(i).direction,'outbound')
            ind = obj_gps(i).save_var_gps(:,1)>lat1;
            if isempty(find(ind)) == 1 
                continue
            end
            temp = obj_gps(i).save_var_gps(ind,:);
            ind = temp(:,1)<lat2;
            if isempty(find(ind)) == 1 
                continue
            end
            temp2 = temp(ind,:);
            ind = temp2(:,2)<long1;
            if isempty(find(ind)) == 1 
                continue
            end
            temp3 = temp2(ind,:);
            ind = temp3(:,2)>long2;
            if isempty(find(ind)) == 1 
                continue
            end
            temp4 = temp3(ind,:);
            mint = min(temp4(:,5))-min(obj_gps(i).save_var_gps(:,5));
            maxt = max(temp4(:,5))-min(obj_gps(i).save_var_gps(:,5));
            if isempty(mint) == 1 || isempty(maxt) == 1
                continue
            end
            if floor(mint*(1.6516e+03)) == 0 || floor(maxt*(1.6516e+03)) == 0 
                continue
            end
            temp5 = obj_ac(i).save_var(floor(mint*(1.6516e+03)):floor(maxt*(1.6516e+03)));
            temp6 = abs(fft(temp5));
            arr(i,:) = [i objs(i).daten var(temp5) max(temp5) min(temp5) mean(temp5) std(temp5) mode(temp5) var(temp6) max(temp6) min(temp6) mean(temp6) std(temp6) mode(temp6)]; 
            disp(i);
       end
    end
end
```

Comment: what value you are passing in `obj_ac` variable  ?

Comment: Post the full error message, there should be more to it than you have posted.

Comment: It seems as some of the error message is missing, but I think that if you posted that it would say "Not enough input arguments". This means that you probably called the function as `myVar = find_by_coor`. You need to give all the arguments as input as `myVar = find_by_coor(arg1, arg2, ...)`. However, in the future, remember that the error cause is as important as where it occurs.

Comment: Sorry I thought that later part of error message is not important so just eliminated it from my post to simplify the discussion. However let me put again the full error message here..

----
`Error in find_by_coor (line 2)
        for i = 1:length(obj_ac)

Output argument "arr" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to
"/Volumes/Untitled/LightRail/find_by_coor.m>find_by_coor"`
----

I called the function as follows:

`rg8_sen4_out = find_by_coor(rg8_ar_ac,rg8_ar_gps,rg8_ar_sen_dir,40.315764,-80.029996,40.330804,-80.030708)`

It seems I put enough arguments...

Comment: @Tom0728 Ok I see, try to add this information to the question. An answer will follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you run the function, the output variable `arr` is never assigned. In Matlab you must always assign a function output if you choose to have it in the definition. For example

```
function [a,b] = setAB()
err = 0; % Gives an error if err is true
a = 1;

if ~err
    b = 1;
end
```

The reason is most certainly that for some inputs, all values fall into one of the if statements and you do never reach the point where `arr` is assigned. A good solution for this is to assign a default value for `arr` in the beginning. That may for example be `nan` or `-1` or, in your case maybe an array `arr = nan(wanted size)` or `arr = -1*ones(wanted size)`. If you do not preallocate `arr` you will likely get a "matrix out of bounds" error instead, should you solve the first issue.

It does not mean that you always need to have an output though.

```
function [] = noOutput()
disp('Hi, I am a void!');
```

You may also choose to return as many values as number of outputs.

```
function varargout = variableArgs()
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 3;

if (nargout == 1)
    varargout{1} = a;
elseif (nargout == 2)
    varargout{1} = b;
    varargout{2} = c;
else
    error('Wrong number of output arguments!');
end
```

I am not saying which of the approaches you should use or that any of them are good. Normally I use `varargout` in case I write plotting functions. Then I may want to return nothing in case I do not have an output argument. Then I want to return handles or any extra information. Further as you may have understood there is also a `varargin` that may be of more use.